# Flash AS3 play movieclip from main timeline on certain frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, playback, movieclip, timeline

I can't seem to find the right script to let my movieclip play when a certain frame reaches on the main timeline. Searched a dozen websites, I'm not quite the coder but hope you guys can tell me the best way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some different solutions for this, the most appropriate would be to not code at all on the timeline. But if you are using the timeline, then write on that specific frame:

```
myMC.gotoAndPlay(frameNumber);
```

Where `myMC` is the `INSTANCE NAME`of the movieclip object placed on the stage (you can change it in the properties panel) and `frameNumber` is the number of the frame where you want to play the movieclip from.

Comment: Hey Zhafur, I actually want all the 6 movieclips at the same time on that frame. If I give a instance name it wont work for them all. What is the solution?

Comment: The instance names are unique, give them different names, or just make count them like myMC1, myMC2, myMC3, then you can run a for cycle and call gotoAndPlay on every mc by saying ["myMC"+i].gotoAndPlay(frameNumber); where "i" is the iterator of the cycle.

Comment: Isn't it possible to call by class?

Comment: If you mean MyClass.gotoAndPlay(frameNumber); then no. You can only call static functions which don't know the instances. So you must store the instances in one form. Storing them in vector is probably the best way, but it's clearly depending on what you want.

Comment: I couldn't get the iteration to work so I did this:

mc1.gotoAndPlay(2);
mc2.gotoAndPlay(2);
mc3.gotoAndPlay(2);
mc4.gotoAndPlay(2);
mc5.gotoAndPlay(2);
mc6.gotoAndPlay(2);

its a little dirty :p

Comment: The for cycle would be more dynamic, but whatever works, mate. :)